# How to integrate Relay server in a working SUP Android project?

Tags: android, sybase, sup

I am a pure Android developer and don't know anything about Sybase Unwired Platform and Relay Server. I have a working SUP based project('m not one who develop it).  I need to integrate Relay server in between SUP and Mobile. The Relay Server is installed and configured to SUP OUTBOUND ENABLER. Relay server port is 80 on SUP Server. But I don't know how to make data transaction through it and show data in android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as easy as changing the ip of the SUP server to the ip address of the relay server, changing the port from the current port number to port 80, setting the messaging farm id and setting the url suffix. When configuring the relay server a backend farm would have been defined with a farm id. This is the id that you would need to enter here. Default relay server url suffix is "`ias_relay_server/client/rs_client.dll`" for Windows based relay server.

These are the properties for the connectionProperties.

You will also need to change the properties for the synchronisation profile. Here you will have to set ip address, port and stream params. Where stream params look something like "`url_suffix=/ias_relay_server/client/rs_client.dll`/"